# I need help with a crowdfunding contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, contract-debugging

This crowdfunding contract is far from complete, I'm still in the process of writing the code and testing each individual function. The approach that I have taken with the getRefund() function seems to work perfectly, however, I'm a little concerned about there being potential collisions as I have mapped all the investor's addresses to the amount of ETH sent to the contract. Is it possible for address A and address B to map to the same index within the mapping? If so, wouldn't this mean that if address A were to claim a refund, wouldn't address A also obtain the funds that were sent from address B?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Crowdfunding {

    address private owner;

    mapping (address => uint) investors;

    //Constructor
    function Crowdfunding() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    //Modifiers
    modifier investorsOnly {
        if(investors[msg.sender] == 0) throw;
        _;
    }

    //Events
    event PaymentReceived(uint Amount, address From, address To);
    event WithdrawalClaimed(uint Amount, address From);

    //Functions
    function() payable {
        investors[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        PaymentReceived(msg.value, msg.sender, this);
    }

    function withdrawFunds() {
        suicide(owner);
    }

    function getRefund() investorsOnly {
        uint amount = investors[msg.sender];
        investors[msg.sender] = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(amount);
        WithdrawalClaimed(amount, msg.sender); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for address A and address B to map to the same index within the mapping?

No, it's not possible because with mapping you define a unique link between the address and the amount contributed. So the refund process should go without troubles. To collide 2 address should have the same private key, and this is almost impossible.

Tip: use revert() instead of throw, that is deprecated.

Also, the fallback function gas cost should be lower than 2300:

> Please ensure you test your fallback function thoroughly to ensure the execution cost is less than 2300 gas before deploying a contract.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have now tested the fallback function and the estimated fee is 42,980 gas. I'm not quite sure how to lower this. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out this too

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://community.ethtools.com/d/3-lets-talk-about-security).

*"The way private keys are generated means that there is a "2160 or about 1 in 1,461,501,637,330,902,918,203,684,832,716,283,019,655,932,542,976" of two private keys colliding.As such, to all extents and purposes addresses are unique."*